# awk compares two column of the same file and print the output in a new column

Tags: file, awk, matching

I am trying to compare values from two column in a txt file in order to identify if valus of the first are major than values of the second one, and than I would like to have a third column saying "here is major" or "here is less".

here an example:

```
col 1                      col 2
0.19727856043434921   0.3970115896012234                   
0.23832706720231472   0.25380634765625        
0.12105356101624322   0.3748512347530257        
0.28048626091230955   0.05645118584277009
```

I would like to have something like

```
col 1                  col 2 
0.19727856043434921   0.3970115896012234        here is less            
0.23832706720231472   0.25380634765625          here is less
0.12105356101624322   0.3748512347530257        here is less
0.28048626091230955   0.05645118584277009       here is major
```

I tried to use awk as follow but is not detecting the truth

```
awk 'OFS="\t" {if( $1>$2) print "here is major"; else if( $1<$2) print "here is less"} ' file.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: When I run your posted code with your samples it works fine for me. Only thing is we need to add `$0` to print line also along with newly added strings like: `awk 'OFS="\t" {if( $1>$2) print $0,"here is major"; else if( $1<$2) print $0,"here is less"} ' `

Comment: Written succinctly: `awk -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1; print $0, $1 < $2 ? "less" : ($1 > $2 ? "more" : "equal")}'`

Comment: @glennjackman that unparenthesized ternary expression used in that context will probably produce a syntax error in some awks. If it was a `>` instead of a `<` I'd say almost certainly but I'm not so sure about the `<`. If you always put parens around your ternaries then you don't have to worry about that and it improves clarity anyway - `print $0, ( $1 < $2 ? "less" : ($1 > $2 ? "more" : "equal") )`

Comment: Gina - regarding "is not detecting the truth", your comparisons look fine (though missing the equality test as Glenn included and missing printing $0 as @RavinderSingh13 points out) so in what way do you feel it "is not detecting the truth"? Is it possible your input is not tab-separated after all?